# Copy to a new google-doc-sheet when dropdown list have selected?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have create a dropdown list on docsheet with "data validation" contains "Approved" and "Rejected". I want all the marked "Rejected" on the dropdown list copied into a new sheets. I am using appscript but dont have an idea. help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us help you, can you provide some samples of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
function copyRejected() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('RENTERS');
  const sr1=3;
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(sr1,1,sh1.getLastRow()-sr1+1,sh1.getLastColumn());
  const v1=rg1.getValues();
  var d=0;
  v1.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[0]=='Rejected') {
      sh2.appendRow(r);
      //sh2.deleteRow(i+sr-d++);//If you wish to delete the copied rows from sh1 then remove forward slashes at the beginning of this line.
    }
  });
}
```

If you haven't enabled V8 then change all of the const to var.

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

[Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)

Comment: absolutely that is what I meant but it is not working for me. maybe because i don't understand how is the data copied. could you explain to me? thanks alot

Comment: it doesn't copying the data to another sheets.

Comment: What column is your validation in ?

Comment: here is the screenshot structure https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FYH1Yd1qvrV0zBTsczu1y2zHYLkUeYhq

Comment: I changed the start row and the name of the source sheet.  What's the name of the second sheet and is in the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi! Mr. Cooper, It's working now it kinda cool. but it will copying the loop again everytime i refreshed.

Comment: What would you expect it to do?

Comment: hi! Mr. Cooper, could you help me by showing the copied sheet1 to the sheet2 exactly including the hidden shell? also, your code will copy the previous validated. I appreciated you very much.

Comment: What's the hidden shell? The code does not copy the validation just the current value.